# Execute shell in post build action jenkins not editable

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am setting up a new job on a new jenkins server. Apparently the Execute Shell task in the Build Step is not working as expected. The Command section of the shell is Not Editable and hence cant put in any commands to test the execution.

I have another jenkins server, where we use this plenty of times and its working perfectly there. Not really sure where is the issue and what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue since Friday and posted the question an hour back to seek any help.
Meanwhile found the solution. As it was working on my another jenkins server, I did side by side plugins comparison and found **Blue Ocean** plugin with difference in the versions. 
At first glance, I couldnt even understand that these would solve the problem but having a read about it https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean/ gave me a feeling as this may solve the problem as it handles the user experience of the Jenkins UI.

Post the upgrade from 1.19.0 to 1.22.0 and restart of jenkins the Execute Shell is working as expected.

Note: I did try restarting the jenikns earlier as well but it didn't help.